# React Native: double fetch overrides previous data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I have a screen with two different tabs. Each tab is indexed (0, 1) and a state keeps the information about the currently active tab. Each tab shows different data on the screen.
When the user taps on a tab, a data fetching starts to obtain tab's data.
In the meanwhile, a loading indicator appears on the screen and when the fetch obtain a response, a dispatch updates the data on the store (redux).
Then the screen re-render, the component got the fetched data from the store and shows the information on the screen.

The problem is when we quickly switch from one tab to another, while a data fetching is already running.
EG: 
- tab 0 starts one fetch to obtain its data, the screen is loading
- we immediately switch to tab 1, before we get the data for tab 0
- tab 1 starts one fetch to obtain its data, the screen is loading
- depending on which fetch finishes first, we have its response data on the screen
- the fetch that finishes later eventually overrides the previous shown data

How can I resolve this issue?
Note: I don't want to disable the switch between tabs while the first fetch is still loading.

Comment: Just abort the older request when a new request is made.

Comment: Thank you @YongQuan, I resolved with the abort controller!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class attribute that will act as a switch.

When you go to tab 0, you set the switch to 0, when you go to tab 1, you set the switch to 1!

Then, in your fetch, you check: If the fetch of tab 0 is finished but your switch is set to 1 (which means that you went back to the tab with index 1), you don't modify the redux store! And vice versa!